# Split a string using a whitespace and CRLF as delimiters C++

Tags: c++, vector, split, delimiter, getline

I have a piece of code that currently splits a string using a whitespace as a delimiter. Each token is stored collectively in a vector of strings.The split function is show below:

```
vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    vector<string> tokens;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        tokens.push_back(item);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

The vector is defined as such:

```
vector<string> mocapVector = split(buffer.str(), ' ');
```

[Example output of the vector can be seen here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckkcw.png)  where an item of the vector is outputted, and the console is shown alongside the original data file (the entire string before it is split.

To reiterate:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

gets outputted  as:

```
a

b

c
d

e

f
g

h

i
```

In the example, only the whitespace is a delimiter, and not CRLF (end of line).
My question is, how can I use both whitespace AND CRLF as delimiters simultaneously, so that each string in the vector is a single token, and not clumps of tokens together?

Ideally would like to avoid using external libraries if at all possible.

Thank you!

EDIT: Solution has been found thanks to @mindriot and @πάνταῥεῖ .

The solution is:

```
vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
        stringstream ss(s);
        string item;
        vector<string> tokens;
        while (ss >> item) {
            tokens.push_back(item);
        }
        return tokens;
    }
```

Thanks to all who responded!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380897/how-to-split-a-sentence-with-an-escaped-whitespace) answer.

Comment: replace first all CRLF with space

Comment: You can simply use `ss >> item;`.

Comment: `'\n'` is end of line. CRLF is Microsoft's notion of how to delimit lines in a text file. In general, you don't have to worry about this detail.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I couldn't get the handwritten parser in the answer you provided to work.

Comment: @Holonout what do you mean?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  what do you mean?

Comment: @PeteBecker how can I incorporate this into the solution?

Comment: @J.Stopher If you are only after `' '` and `'\n'` delimiters that statement I mentioned already does it correctly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  That is exactly what I'm after. Where do I put that statement?

Comment: @J.Stopher it should replace your `getline` call.

Comment: @mindriot and πάνταῥεῖ  Thank you, it works!!